# Target clustered markers only with getAllChildMarkers()

Tags: leaflet

I'm on a leaflet map project. I'm working with a geoJson file; I'm looking a way to target the markers that are inside a cluster, in order to show their respective datas in a dynamic div;
I have an OnEachFeature function, in which I build all the html to display my datas properly.

If I add :

```
clusters.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
    // a.layer is actually a cluster
    console.log('cluster ' + a.layer.getAllChildMarkers().length);
});
```

When I click on a cluster that have 2 markers, It shows me the number "2" in console..
[image]

But when I try to loop in it, it displays all my geoJson data for all markers of my map, instead of just the selected one.

```
clusters.on('clusterclick', function(a){
    if(a.layer._zoom == 18){
    var markers = a.layer.getAllChildMarkers();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        $('#layer_infos .fill').append(html);
    }   
  }
})
```

With this, I get also exactly the same results..so I don't understand.

```
clusters.on('clusterclick', function(a){
    if(a.layer._zoom == 18){            
    $('#layer_infos .fill').append(html);                                       
    }
})
```

Can someone help me target only the clustered markers ?

I saw [this turorial](https://digital-geography.com/working-with-clusters-in-leaflet-increasing-useability/), which does exactly what I'm after, but I'm unable to use their code in my project, becaus all my html is inside a variable..

**EDIT:**

Here is my onEachFeature function :

```
 function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

        var html = '';
        if (feature.properties.Professeur) {
            html += '<p class="prof">' + feature.properties.Professeur + '</p>';
        }
         if (feature.properties.Professeur2) {
            html += '<p class="prof2">' + feature.properties.Professeur2 + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Chu) {
            html += '<p class="chu">' + feature.properties.Chu + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Laboratoire) {
            html += '<p class="labo">' + feature.properties.Laboratoire + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Prelevement) {
            html += '<p>' + feature.properties.Prelevement + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Envoi) {
            html += '<p>' + feature.properties.Envoi + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Adresse) {
            html += '<p class="adress">' + feature.properties.Adresse + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Cp) {
            html += '<p class="cp">' + feature.properties.Cp + '</p>';
        }

        if (feature.properties.Tel) {
            html += '<p class="tel">' + feature.properties.Tel + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Fax) {
            html += '<p class="fax">' + feature.properties.Fax + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Mail) {
            html += '<p class="mail"><a href="mailto:' + feature.properties.Mail +'">' + feature.properties.Mail + '</a></p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Tel2) {
            html += '<p class="tel">' + feature.properties.Tel2 + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Fax2) {
            html += '<p class="fax">' + feature.properties.Fax2 + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Mail2) {
            html += '<p class="mail"><a href="mailto:' + feature.properties.Mail2 +'">' + feature.properties.Mail2 + '</a></p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Renseignement) {
            html += '<p class="rt">' + feature.properties.Renseignement + '</p>';
        }
        if (feature.properties.Url) {
            html += '<p class="url"><a href="' + feature.properties.Url + '">' + feature.properties.Url + '</a></p>';
        }
      html+='<div class="pictos">';


        if (feature.properties.Examen) {
            html += '<span class="' + feature.properties.Examen + '">' + feature.properties.Examen + '</span>';
        }

            html+='</div>';

        layer.on('click', function() {
            $('#layer_infos .fill').html(html);

            if (L.Browser.mobile) {
                $('#infos').addClass("slide"); 
                $('#filters').removeClass('slide');
                $('.hamburger').text('Sélectionner un examen').fadeIn();
             }
        }) 


        clusters.on('clusterclick', function(a){
            if(a.layer._zoom == 18){

                $('#layer_infos .fill').append(html);
            }



        })
    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `html` inside that loop?

Comment: Thanks Ivan. My html contains all geojson properties for each marker...

Comment: ...so where are you assigning a value to `html`, i.e. how does your `var html = ...` code looks like?

Comment: Thanks again Ivan, I edited my question.

Comment: The value of `html` is always the one from the last run of the loop, not what you think it's the "current" value. You have a *variable scope* problem, and you should read about closures e.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work . Also, think how many times you attach event handlers to the `MarkerCluster` group (`clusters.on('clusterclick',...`). Even if you got the closures right, that's useless if there's one event handler per feature because *all* features will trigger something on *any* cluster marker.

Comment: Yes I understand. Thank you for your comment. Effectivly if I place it outside of my onEachFeature it doen't recognize the html var, so I'm stuck with my structure !. I've learned from this tutorial, http://zevross.com/blog/2014/10/28/tips-for-creating-leafleft-js-maps/  . Thank you anyway for taking a bit of your time !!

Comment: What's missing in this code is also how/where you construct your markers and add them to cluster layer.